# How to convert cctv footage to h265 for streaming and recording in nginx-rtmp module?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, h.264, rtmp

I am using the `nginx-rtmp-module` [here](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) to pull an `rtsp` stream from a camera on local network and convert it to `rtmp`. This `rtmp` stream is then converted to `hls` and made available for livestreaming. It is also being recorded in 5 min segments. (these things can all be seen in the `nginx.conf` below).

I want to change the video codec to `h265` to save storage space, since each 5 min video is `~230mb`, and using `opencv` and `python`, I was able to get `<100mb` per 5 min video using `h265`, so I know there is a lot of space for storage saving.

How can I change the codec of the stream to `h265`?

I have tried installing `libx265-dev` and setting `-vcodec libx265`, however this tells me `flv` is an invalid container and I'm getting nowhere with finding a valid container for streaming + recording.

My `nginx.conf`:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port

        application relay {
            
            live on;

            hls on;
            hls_path /tmp/hls;
            hls_fragment 15s;


            exec_static /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i rtsp://test:test@192.168.100.10:8554/fhd -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/relay/fhd; 

            # record block  
            record video;
            record_path /tmp/hls;
            record_unique on;
            record_interval 5m;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The RTMP protocol does not have support for the h.265 codec. There is no standard way to do this.

Comment: Rough! Is there maybe a streaming protocol that does support the codec and has something similar to the nginx-rtmp-module that I can use to stream + record cctv footage?